# cannot find symbol import com.google.android.gms.R

Tags: android, eclipse, mobile-application

i'm getting this error "cannot find symbol import com.google.android.gms.R" while trying to execute app in android studio,
app was developed in eclipse and imported to android studio.

```
 Error details:
    symbol:   class R
    location: package com.google.android.gms
 Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
 Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
 1 error
 :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
 > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

 * Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow :). You might want to detail your question a bit more: can you please post the code that is causing you trouble? Please take a look here: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Build->clean project and then Build->Rebuild project, File->Invalidate caches and restart. These may work, not sure. I used to do these steps usually for these kind of errors

Comment: yes, actually many times, it cleans other errors but this one is still appear